# What do you call a widget that holds the side of a curtain against a wall?

Tags: windows, curtain-rail

I moved into a house and found these handy widgets screwed into a bedroom wall.  These widgets each consist of a hook-shaped piece of metal with a small clip that fastens a window curtain to the hook.  These are very handy for keeping light from shining around the curtain while I'm napping.

This is completely separate from the rod that the curtain hangs from.  They are at about breast height.

I wanted to buy some more of these, but I don't know what to ask for at the hardware store and it's tricky to describe it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called **[safety cup hooks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004Z0Q4)** and have been cleverly repurposed.

[image: safety cup hook]

```
Links are for illustration purposes only. No product or source is being endorsed.
```

Comment: While that's what they are, you likely want to be searching for what HerrBag mentioned. The proper term/device is a 'curtain tie back'. It's essentially the same thing, but larger, and usually designed to look nicer.

Comment: @DA01 I thought that too initially, but since his purpose is to hold the edge of the curtain to the wall to keep light out, tiebacks won't work. He may *also* want tiebbacks for gathering the curtain in an open position.

Comment: What where they originally created for?  Do they go back to ship rigging or is it more modern?

Answer (score 1):

Curtain tie backs
[etsy page of tie backs](https://www.etsy.com/search?q=curtain%20tie%20backs)